# Create Lookup Field on Query-Based Form

Tags: ms-access-2010

I created a form based on a query.
I would like to add to the form a lookup field in order to enable selecting value from a drop-down list.

I found instructions for creating a lookup field in a form based on a table.
Is it possible to create such a field on a query-based forum? how?

Answer (score 0):

It is quiet easy:

1. Add a combo box to your form (I tried on a query-based form).
2. Use the combobox wizard to set its values from an existing table.
3. Select the wanted columns to be defined as the combo box values.